# Bug: createdDateTime is null in /beta/users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When calling the Microsoft Graph API to get a specific user, the createdDateTime field is returned without any data.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/user@domain.com
```

However, when searching for the user, the field is returned correctly.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=startsWith(userPrincipalName, 'user@domain.com')
```

The bug can be reproduced using the GraphExlorer web-site: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

I'm not sure where to report this, so I posted it here.

Comment: I get null for createdDateTime with both approaches. :-/

Comment: I am definitely seeing inconsistent results here with the createdDateTime field on multiple GET operations for same user as well. It would be great if someone from Microsoft could look into this as this does not instill confidence. And with no reply here from MS since you posted this, and me observing the same issue some 5+ months later...what are we left with?

@philippe-signoret - Can you please help with this one?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found the answer.

When I do a GET operation using the Azure AD 'id' the createdDateTime is populated.  When I retrieve the same user using the userPrincipalName, the createdDateTime value is returned as null.  I suppose the issue is that the value is retrievable by the back-end query when the Azure AD 'id' property is used while the userPrincipalName (which is a mutable/changeable property) is not.  Bizarre, but at least there seems to be an answer.